# Despite IE, @font-face not working in Chrome and FireFox

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, fonts, font-face

Sorry, this question might be duplicated, but I couldn't find any answer to my problem.
implimenting @font-face in css works properly in IE but in FireFox and Chrome has no effect.
I want to add a non-standard font to my web site, so I put the files Snazanin.ttf and Snaznnbd.ttf to the same directory as css file and added the following code to css:

```
@font-face{
        font-family: MyFont;
        src:url('Snazanin.ttf')format('truetype')   ;
    }
    @font-face{
        font-family: MyFont;
        src:url('Snaznnbd.ttf')format('truetype');
        font-weight: bold;  
    }
```

and in another css file I have:

```
#mainframe{
    width:666px;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    font-family:MyFont;
}
```

also in the same directory, I have the file .htaccess which contains:

```
AddType font/ttf .ttf
```

as I mentioned earlier, there is no problem with IE but chrome and FireFox fail to show MyFont
thanks for answering

Comment: Use WOFF format for Chrome, Opera, Safari and FF. Use EOT format for IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it has to do with the browser's support of the filetype.
Here's a few quick references:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

http://caniuse.com/ttf

http://caniuse.com/woff

http://caniuse.com/eot

http://caniuse.com/svg-fonts

You may want to supply multiple font files. As per the w3schools link, a ttf/eot mix should have you covered.

Comment: Thanks Duncan for the references.